# Why cant I access .TrimSafe?

Tags: c#

Copied some code from one controller to another. Both files have the same using statements but it wont 'resolve' this issue for me.

On my first file `address.Name.Value = source.Name.TrimSafe();`
is fine however on my second file. .TrimSafe flags up as does not exist
From the telescense i can choose trim, trimEnd or trimStart where has trimSafe gone to and why cant I use it?

Comment: Are both files using the same namespace?

Comment: no, but they should be different

Comment: take a look at your list of "using" directives in the first file and compare them with the second file. TrimSafe() may be an extension method that is not being imported in the second file.

Comment: the using statements are all copied from one to the other

Comment: Where is TrimSafe defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TrimSafe()` is not a standard .NET method. This would suggest that `TrimSafe()` exists as a method in your first file, but never got copied over to the second, and it's a either a private function or non-static function.

I would clean & rebuild your project as well.

Comment: Nope, doesnt exist as a method in the first file. 'source' is a VM which doesnt mentioned anything about trimsafe in it. Also clean and rebuild didnt work but thanks

Comment: I would add that if it is static, he needs to be `using` the namespace it's in.

Comment: It was in a strinExtension.cs file inside the original namespace folder thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a namespace issue to me.

Consider this:

```
// In some file somewhere
namespace firstNamespace
{
    Class MyString : String
    {
        public static TrimSafe() {}
    }
}

// The first file you copied from
namespace firstNamespace
{
    public void foo() { TrimSafe(); } // Works!
}

namespace secondNamespace
{
    public void fee() { TrimSafe(); } // Nope :(
}
```

To fix the last one, you need to add `using firstNamespace;` at the top with the other using statements.  The reason would be that the first file you're copying from is in the same namespace as where TrimSafe is defined.

In C++ you typically `#include` all of the referenced .h files for each class that you use.

In C#, you don't add `using` statements for classes, but instead for namespaces.  You only need to be `using` the namespace, and everything inside of that namespace comes along with it. Anything defined in namespace `xyz` sees everything else defined in namespace `xyz` without having to have a `using` for each class.

Your second file is in a different namespace, and so it has no idea what is in the first namespace, and so it doesn't see TrimSafe.

That's my guess anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Looks familiar, I guess you're doing the Orchard Webshop tutorials as well :)
You need to add a folder in your project called Helpers, and it should have this class in it:

```
    public static class StringExtensions {
    public static string TrimSafe(this string s) {
        return s == null ? string.Empty : s.Trim();
    }
}
```

Just include the namespace where your method is needed.